# <BadPtr> Error on Loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm receiving a BadPtr error whenever I reach this point into the code: Why?

```
for(int i = 0; i < processTable.size(); i++)
        {
            data_entry test = *processTable.at(i).dataCurrent; //ERROR
            cout << test.text << "\n";
        }
```

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum process_state { READY, RUNNING, WAITING };

struct data_entry {
    const char * text;
    int time;
};

struct process_entry
{
    int process;
    const data_entry * dataStart;
    const data_entry * dataEnd;
    const data_entry * dataCurrent;
    process_state state;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<data_entry> dataTable;
    vector<process_entry> processTable;

    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("C:\\Users\\1162852\\Documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\Project 1 (OS)\\Debug\\input.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int processAmount = 0;

        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            if(line.find("START") != string::npos)
            {
                data_entry newEntry;
                newEntry.text = "START";
                newEntry.time = atoi(line.substr(6, 6).c_str());
                dataTable.push_back(newEntry);

                process_entry newProcessEntry;
                newProcessEntry.dataStart = &dataTable.at(dataTable.size() - 1);
                newProcessEntry.dataCurrent = &dataTable.at(dataTable.size() - 1);
                newProcessEntry.process = processAmount;
                processTable.push_back(newProcessEntry);

                processAmount += 1;
            }
            else if(line.find("END") != string::npos)
            {
                data_entry newEntry;
                newEntry.text = "END";
                newEntry.time = NULL;
                dataTable.push_back(newEntry);

                processTable.at(processTable.size() - 1).dataEnd = &dataTable.at(dataTable.size() - 1);
            }
            else if(line.find("RUN") != string::npos)
            {
                data_entry newEntry;
                newEntry.text = "RUN";
                newEntry.time = atoi(line.substr(4, 4).c_str());
                dataTable.push_back(newEntry);
            }
            else if(line.find("INPUT") != string::npos)
            {
                data_entry newEntry;
                newEntry.text = "INPUT";
                newEntry.time = atoi(line.substr(6, 6).c_str());
                dataTable.push_back(newEntry);
            }
            else if(line.find("SSD") != string::npos)
            {
                data_entry newEntry;
                newEntry.text = "SSD";
                newEntry.time = atoi(line.substr(4, 4).c_str());
                dataTable.push_back(newEntry);
            }
        }

        //reverse(dataTable.begin(),dataTable.end());
        /*for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << dataTable.at(i).text << "\n";
        }*/

        for(int i = 0; i < processTable.size(); i++)
        {
            data_entry test = *processTable.at(i).dataCurrent;
            cout << test.text << "\n";
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    int test;
    cin >> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give the **EXACT** error you are receiving when you compile.

Comment: A pointer to an element in a vector become *invalid* when you add elements to the vector.  Have a look-see what shared_ptr<> can do.

Comment: @Hans is right, the problem is that you are saving a pointer to elements of `dataTable` but `push_back` will invalidate those pointers if the vector is resized.  Consider making `dataTable` and `processTable` a vector of shared pointers so they don't get moved.

Comment: @Rastaban Would I do something like: vector<shared_ptr<data_entry>> dataTable;

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer below so to show a longer example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving a pointer to elements of `dataTable` but `push_back` will invalidate those pointers if the vector is resized. Consider making `dataTable` and `processTable` a vector of shared pointers so they don't get moved.

```
vector<shared_ptr<data_entry>> dataTable;
vector<shared_ptr<process_entry>> processTable;
```

I would also change the members of process_entry to shared pointers while your at it.  With these changes your START section will now look something like this:

```
            auto newEntry = make_shared<data_entry>();
            newEntry->text = "START";
            newEntry->time = atoi(line.substr(6, 6).c_str());
            dataTable.push_back(newEntry);

            auto newProcessEntry = make_shared<process_entry>();
            newProcessEntry->dataStart = dataTable.back();
            newProcessEntry->dataCurrent = dataTable.back();
            newProcessEntry->process = processAmount;
            processTable.push_back(newProcessEntry);
```

Another option you have is to use a `std::list` which won't copy the elements around when it grows.

Answer (score 2):

This assignment should return a data entry type.
Use `->dataCurrent` to obtain the pointer to data_entry, and then dereference.
You perhaps also want to specify data_entry as const depending on what it is used for.

```
const data_entry test = *(processTable.at(i)->dataCurrent);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
*processTable.at(i).dataCurrent;
```

by

```
*(processTable.at(i).dataCurrent);
```

Moreover you do not have copy ctor and thus a shallow copy is made. 
Make sure this is what u want.

Answer (score 0):

You populated your `vectors` with local variables that are created inside the `while` loop, and they are not accessible out of the enclosing `if` block.

So once we exit the while block all the local variables are destroyed, and the `vector` is pointing to bunch of `bad_ptr`s.